# Can my macro detect if the action was successful?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I have a fairly straightforward macro to announce a Raise target in public groups:

```
/micon "Raise"
/ac "Raise" <t>
/p Raise on <t>
```

Sometimes my Raise doesn't go through.  Either I'm out of range and didn't notice or my spells were still on the GCD when I tried to Raise while dodging mechanics, and I have to activate the macro again, leading to a number of duplicate lines in party chat.

Is there a way to only announce the Raise if the cast was successful?  This would also help me notice my cast failed because the error text is often hard to see (especially in red environments), but party chat is easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this isn't possible. We're already allowed to write the macros and "pseudo" script. But allowing this would open the door to even more automation inside the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but IIRC there's a workaround.

You can see how long a Raise would need to be channeled before successfully cast. Generally it's somewhere around 3-4.5 seconds (haven't played in a while). You can have the macro wait as long as 10 seconds (only integers) before continuing. You can set the wait to be around 4 seconds and if you've triggered another wait in another macro, there's a very high chance your Raise failed, so you did something else

Do bear in mind that this timer is global. All macros share a single timer, so you can't put timers that can remind you that your spells are ready to cast. I tried.

Comment: I just wanted to add 2 things.  1. You can make the script do something like /ac "raise" <t> <wait.4.0> to cast raise and wait 4 seconds (i think that works with <t> skills).  2. make sure to give it a little bit of leeway to include for lag.